# How is a template function call resolved

Tags: c++, templates

I am well aware of the fact that the template function basically gets compiled at the point when there is a specific invocation. But in this question I am looking for something different.

I have the following source files :

a.cpp :

```
template <class T>
void g(T x) {
    cout<<x<<"  g#1\n" ;
}
void f() ;
main() {
    g(10) ;
    g('c') ;
    f() ;
}
```

b.cpp :

```
template <class T>
void g(T x) {
    cout<<x<<"  g#2\n" ;
}
void f() {
    g(11) ;
}
```

Now when I compile the code as :

```
g++ a.cpp b.cpp
```

all the three calls to g (2 in main and one in function 'f') are resolved via the template function defined in a.cpp.

But when I compile the code as :

```
g++ b.cpp a.cpp
```

the call g(10) in main and g(11) in function 'f' are resolved via the template function defined in b.cpp while the call g('c') in main is resolved via the template function defined in a.cpp

Of course if the template function defined in either of the two files is removed there is a compiler error reported by that particular file.

Can someone please provide an explanation for all these observations

In particular I want to know what kind of function call resolution is taking place during object file generation a.o and b.o. My query is as to how is the call resolved at compile time, i.e when I say :

```
g++ -c a.cpp
```

and

```
g++ -c b.cpp
```

and then what happens when I say :

```
g++ a.o b.o
```

Comment: one-definition-rule violation detected.

Comment: @Deduplicator Don't you have this one on your SO fav's list? ;) ...

Comment: @Deduplicator You mean by the code or by the question? ;-)

Comment: @Angew: Naturally both.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I have edited the question, hope now my question is more clearer

Comment: @user3282758 Doesn't help. Your answer is still given in the dupe. You're violating ODR.

Comment: OK @πάνταῥεῖ, So I checked up the ODR wiki and as per that **A program consisting of multiple header files and source files will typically have more than one definition of a type, but not more than one definition per translation unit.If a program contains more than one definition of a type, then each definition must be equivalent**. So now my query is what will happen if the definitions in this case are not equivalent - is the compiler behaviour undefined ?

Comment: @user3282758 Do you mean _template specializations_ actually? These could appear within a particular TU, not multiply though.